# Dynamically Adding Rows not Inserting Records - Null JSON

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, dynamic, table

I Have created a LWC to dynamically add rows and insert the records, but the insert is failing with the error below

```
message :"null input to JSON parser"
stackTrace: "(System Code)\nClass.RingInsert_Handler.insertRings: line 5, column 1"
```

This works if I use a standard object, but not with my custom Ring Object.   Below are my components

**JS**

```
import {LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
import insertRings from '@salesforce/apex/RingInsert_Handler.insertRings'
import {ShowToastEvent} from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

export default class LwcDynamicRecordRowsCreation extends LightningElement {

    @track listOfRings;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.initData();
    }

    initData() {
        let listOfRings = [];
        this.createRow(listOfRings);
        this.listOfRings = listOfRings;
    }

    createRow(listOfRings) {
        let ringObject = {};
        if(listOfRings.length > 0) {
            ringObject.index = listOfRings[listOfRings.length - 1].index + 1;
        } else {
            ringObject.index = 1;
        }
        ringObject.Name = null;
        ringObject.Ring_Town__c = null;
        ringObject.Ring_Objective__c = null;
        listOfRings.push(ringObject);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new row
     */
    addNewRow() {
        this.createRow(this.listOfRings);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the selected row
     */
    removeRow(event) {
        let toBeDeletedRowIndex = event.target.name;

        let listOfRings = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.listOfRings.length; i++) {
            let tempRecord = Object.assign({}, this.listOfRings[i]); //cloning object
            if(tempRecord.index !== toBeDeletedRowIndex) {
                listOfRings.push(tempRecord);
            }
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < listOfRings.length; i++) {
            listOfRings[i].index = i + 1;
        }

        this.listOfRings = listOfRings;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all rows
     */
    removeAllRows() {
        let listOfRings = [];
        this.createRow(listOfRings);
        this.listOfRings = listOfRings;
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        let index = event.target.dataset.id;
        let fieldName = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        for(let i = 0; i < this.listOfRings.length; i++) {
            if(this.listOfRings[i].index === parseInt(index)) {
                this.listOfRings[i][fieldName] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    createRings() {
        insertRings({
            jsonOflistOfRings: JSON.stringify(this.listOfRings)
        })
            .then(data => {
                this.initData();
                let event = new ShowToastEvent({
                    message: "Rings successfully created!",
                    variant: "success",
                    duration: 2000
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(event);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-card" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="slds-card__header slds-media slds-media_center">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body slds-card__header-title slds-text-title_bold" style="font-size: 14px">
                Ring Creation
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Table -->
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table_cell-buffer" role="grid">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Objective</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Town</th> 
                <th scope="col" height="22" style="width: 3rem"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <template for:each={listOfRings} for:item="rec">
                <tr key={rec} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Name" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Ring_Town__c" value={rec.Ring_Town__c} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Ring_Objective__c" value={rec.Ring_Objective__c} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Remove" title="Remove" name={rec.index} onclick={removeRow}></lightning-button-icon>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="slds-p-left_small slds-p-vertical_small">
            <lightning-button class="slds-p-right_small" variant="destructive" label="delete all rows" title="delete all rows" icon-name="utility:recycle_bin_full" onclick={removeAllRows}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="add additional row" title="add additional row" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={addNewRow}></lightning-button>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer" style="padding: 0.50rem 1rem;">
            <lightning-button icon-name="utility:save" variant="brand" label="Create Rings" title="Create Rings" onclick={createRings}></lightning-button>
        </footer>
    </div>

</template>
```

**CLS**

```
public without sharing class RingInsert_Handler {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void insertRings(String jsonOfListOfRings) {
        List<Ring__c> listOfRings = (List<Ring__c>) JSON.deserialize(jsonOfListOfRings, List<Ring__c>.class);
        insert listOfRings;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how JavaScript interacts with the server, the parameters are case sensitive.

Apex: `jsonOfListOfRings`

JavaScript: `jsonOflistOfRings`

The L is not capitalized, so it's not received in the Apex code.

---

Side note: you can avoid the serialization entirely. Just pass in an appropriate object.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void insertRings(Ring__c[] rings) {
    insert rings;
}
```

---

```
let ringObject = { sobjectType: 'Ring__c' };
```

...

```
createRings() {
    const { rings } = this;
    insertRings({
        rings
    })
    // ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks! Once again you have provided a very simple solution along with details.  I really appreciate your effort!